# Generate multiple answers and put in list without using findall/3

Tags: prolog

the below code works perfectly but i want to get the multiple answers in a list without using the `findall/3` function.

```
bet(N, M, K) :- N =< M, K = N.
bet(N, M, K) :- N < M, N1 is N+1, bet(N1, M, K).

pred([X, Y, S, P], N) :-
    N1 is N - 1,
    bet(2, N1, X),
    X1 is X + 1,
    N2 is N - X,
    bet(X1, N2, Y),
    S is X + Y,
    P is X * Y.

s1(Q, N) :-
    findall(X, pred(X, N), Q).
```

Had some help getting the above code work coz i'm new to Prolog.
Also, what the program is supposed to do is this:

> X and Y are two integers with 1 < X < Y and X + Y ≤ 100. The goal
>   s1(Q,100) will bind Q with a list of quadruples [X, Y, S, P], where S
>   = X + Y and P = X * Y.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093887/more-trouble-with-prolog-list-building

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to break your `pred/2` down to a recursive. auxiliary predicate that handles one case of `X` and `Y` on each recursive call. The following may not be optimized, but you can see in the logical tests how it achieves this:

```
pred(Q, N) :-
    pred(Q, 2, 3, N). % Start with values X=2, Y=3

pred([], X, _, N) :-  % Case in which X has reached max, so we're done
    X >= N.
pred(Q, X, Y, N) :-   % Case in which X is in range, but Y is at max, so next X, restart Y
    X < N,
    Y >= N - X,
    X1 is X + 1,
    Y1 is X1 + 1,
    pred(Q, X1, Y1, N).
pred([[X, Y, S, P]|Qs], X, Y, N) :-  % Case in which X and Y are within range
    X < N,
    Y < N - X,
    S is X + Y,
    P is X * Y,
    Y1 is Y + 1,
    pred(Qs, X, Y1, N).              % Recurse using next Y
```

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot!